# How to obtain the torque from a magnetic moment Lagrangian?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, torque, angular-velocity, magnetic-moment

Consider a body with magnetic dipole moment $\vec m$ subject to a magnetic field $\vec B$.

We know that the torque on the body will be given by:
\begin{equation}
\vec \tau = \vec m \wedge \vec B
\end{equation}

I am trying to obtain this same torque expression from a Lagrangian approach.

Considering $\vec \omega$ the angular momentum of the body, the lagrangian will have a kinetic and a ``potential" term. The interaction energy of a magnetic moment and field are:
\begin{equation}
U = - \vec m \cdot \vec B
\end{equation}

For an aligned magnetic dipole moment and spin we have further $\vec m = \gamma I \vec\omega$, for a constant $\gamma$ and moment of inertia $I$. Thus I have written:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L(\vec \omega) = T - V = \frac{1}{2}I \omega^2 + \gamma I \vec \omega \cdot \vec B
\end{equation}

From the E.L. equations, I have been able to derive the following relation, always valid as long as the Lagrangian is only dependent on $\vec \omega$ (and as long as I haven't made a mistake):
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \vec \omega}(\vec \omega) = \vec\omega \wedge \mathcal L(\vec \omega)
\end{equation}
(The derivation is a bit long so it is best not to include it here. I can give more details if required, but suffice to say I obtained this from considering an extended Lagrangian with non-independent orientation variables plus constraints...)

So what we can conclude is that,
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dt} \left(I \vec\omega + \gamma I \vec B \right) &= \vec\omega \wedge \left(I \vec\omega + \gamma I \vec B \right) \\
&= \gamma \left(I \vec\omega + \gamma I \vec B \right) \wedge \vec B
\end{align}
This is similar to a "torque equation" for a kind of "canonical spin"?

Alternatively, we may expand the above for the physical spin, as
\begin{align}
 \tilde\tau \equiv \frac{d I \vec\omega }{dt}  &= \gamma I \vec\omega \wedge \vec B - \gamma I \frac{d \vec B}{dt} \\
&= \vec m \wedge \vec B - \gamma I \frac{d \vec B}{dt} \\
\end{align}
We see the presence of an extra term from what was expected... (time derivative of $\vec B$)

So what is the difference between the two approaches? Have I made a mistake somewhere? Or failed to make some considerations?

Thanks!!